# CsScript with Mono: How to make mono not treat warnings as errors

Tags: c#, mono, cs-script

I use CSScriptLibrary.dll to execute C# code in my application which runs on both Windows and Linux. Problem is, right now, I need to use `#pragma disable warning` to disable all kinds of warnings that may arise in order to get the scripts to compile on Mono which is a very ugly hack.

```
// the following simple script will not execute on Mono due to a warning that a is not used.
var code = "public class Script { public object Run() { var a=1; return 2+3; }}"
// here is how the script is executed using CsScriptLibrary
try
{
    var asm = new AsmHelper(CSScript.LoadCode(code, "cs", null, true));
    // if we reach that point, the script compiled
    var obj = asm.CreateAndAlignToInterface<IScript>("*");
    // now run it:
    var result=obj.Run();
}
catch (CompilerException e)
{
    // on .net compiler exceptions are only raised when there are errors
    // on mono I get an exception here, even for warnings like unused variable
}
```

I already tried to set the default compiler parameters of CSScript to instruct the mono compiler to disregard warnings. Here is what I tried (based on documentation of compiler switches of Mono compiler:

```
CSScript.GlobalSettings.DefaultArguments = "-warn:0 -warnaserror-";
```

But I had no success and I am not even sure if this is the right way to go. Anyway, for the sake of completeness I note here that `CSScript.GlobalSettings.DefaultArguments` defaults to `/c /sconfig /co:/warn:0` in CSScript.

Does anyone know how to get `CSScript.LoadCode` to disregard warnings on Mono or at least not treat them as errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions (found with help of Oleg Shilo). You can either include the desired compiler option directly in the script:

```
//css_co -warn:0 
using System;
...
```

or you can substitute `CSScript.LoadCode` with `LoadWithConfig`, which allows passing compiler options directly. Something like this:

```
static public Assembly LoadCode(string scriptText, bool debugBuild, params string[] refAssemblies)
{
    string tempFile =  System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +".cs";        
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
            sw.Write(scriptText);        
        return LoadWithConfig(scriptFile, null, debugBuild, CSScript.GlobalSettings, "-warn:0", refAssemblies);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!debugBuild)
        {
            //delete temp file
        }
    }
}
```

It should be noted, that the second solution will bypass the built in assembly caching performed in LoadCode. It is easy enough to cache the compiled script object though.